# Setting the position of a text geometry?

Tags: javascript, text, three.js, position

I have looked through stack overflow and google and I have found how to CENTER a text geometry but that is not what I want to do.

I have a scene that just has a block of text that says "Buy Here!". Using the documentation in the three.js website and examples here I was able to do that after some struggling. I had some trouble finding out how to refer to that mesh since I had created the geometry inside a function, and it took hours for me to know about setting a name for it as a string so it can be accessible from different parent/child levels.

What I am NOT able to do now is to offset the text by some arbitrary number of units. I tried shifting it down by 5 units. No matter how I try to do it it isn't working. I either manage to make the text geometry disappear OR my whole scene is black.

Here is my code...

I have the basic scene setup working properly and I'll include it here but feel free to skip since I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with the issue...

```
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import TWEEN from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tweenjs/tween.js@18.5.0/dist/tween.esm.js';

//BASIC SCENE SETUP
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

//LIGHTS (POINT AND AMBIENT)
const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
pointLight.position.set(5, 5, 5);
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF);
scene.add(pointLight, ambientLight);

//RESIZE WINDOW
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    render();
}, false);

//ORBIT CONTROLS
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.minDistance = 5;
controls.maxDistance = 70;
controls.enablePan = false;
controls.enableRotate = false;
controls.enableZoom = false;
controls.target.set(0,0,-1);
camera.position.setZ(25);

window.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        onClick(event);
    })

window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    
var animate = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    render();
    TWEEN.update();
        
};
    
function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
    
animate();
```

and here is my code for the text object....

```
var loaderF = new THREE.FontLoader();
    loaderF.load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/fonts/optimer_regular.typeface.json', function ( font ) {
        var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Buy Here!', {
            font: font,
            size: 2.3,
            height: 0.1,
            curveSegments: 15,
            bevelEnabled: true,
            bevelThickness: 0.5,
            bevelSize: 0.31,
            bevelSegments: 7
        } );
        geometry.center();
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x686868});
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        mesh.name = "bhText"
        scene.add( mesh );
        mesh.userData = { URL: "http://google.com"};
    } );
```

Here's what I have tried.....

under "var geometry ({...});" I typed....

```
geometry.position.setX(-5);
```

but the text object disappears completely so I tried

```
geometry.position.setX = -5;
```

but there was no difference so i tried taking out

```
geometry.center();
```

but it had the same results.

So then I tried using

```
mesh.position.x = -5;
```

with AND without

```
geometry.center();
```

but again, they all just make my text object disappear.

So now I tried to set the position from outside the function by typing the following code OUTSIDE of everything that is contained in

loaderF.load ('https.....', function (font){var geometry = .....})

using the reference I learned....

```
scene.getObjectByName("bhText").position.x(-5);
```

but this makes my entire scene go blank (black). So I tried variations of like

```
scene.getObjectByName("bhText").position.x = -5;
scene.getObjectByName("bhText").position.setX(-5);
scene.getObjectByName("bhText").position.setX = -5;
mesh.position.setX = -5;// I was pretty sure this wasn't going to work since I wasn't 
                        //using the mesh name specifically for when it's inside something
                        //I can't reach because of parent-child relations
```

and again trying each of those with AND without

```
geometry.center();
```

but they all made my scene go black.

I just wanna move it down a couple of units. Sheesh.

Could anyone be kind enough to tell me WHERE in my code I can set the position of the text geometry? Thank you please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just wanna move it down a couple of units.

In this case use `mesh.position.y = - 5;`. Changing the `x` coordinate will move the mesh to the left or right. Here is a complete live example based on your code:

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 10 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
pointLight.position.set(5, 5, 5);

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF);
scene.add(pointLight, ambientLight);

const loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/fonts/optimer_regular.typeface.json', function(font) {
  const geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry('Buy Here!', {
    font: font,
    size: 2,
    height: 0.5
  });
  geometry.center();
  const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0x686868
  });
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.position.y = - 1; // FIX
  
  mesh.name = "bhText"
  scene.add(mesh);
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  
});
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.130.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was using the x coordinate just because i wanted to move it in any direction because it wasn't working. The issue must have had to have been something else because i tried the very thing you suggested but as I read your message today I even did a ctrl+z to look at when i typed the mesh.position.y=-2; (i originally wanted it down 2 units) a few days ago and that worked. So I must have had it correct before and something else  was the cause. I still dont know and it's frustrating how often this happens.

Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: a question i do have is that what if i wanted to trigger that movement from within an if function later on in my code? I can't use "mesh" at that point because my screen goes black. I tried using
scene.getObjectByName("bhText") to refer to it but this doesn't work. Is there a proper way to refer to this regardless of where i am in the code?

Comment: A simple solution for this is to declare the `mesh` variable outside of the `onLoad()` callback. For example in the same scope where you declare the `renderer` variable. You should then be able to use the reference anywhere in your code.